# Forwarding of an object's public attributes/vars in API Responses a good practice?

Tags: rest, api-design

So one of our API's has the function of receiving limited raw data, enriching it, and then returning it to the requestor. Currently the controller explicitly builds the response object. However since we constantly increase the attributes/variables in the response the controller is becoming rather Phat (Yes with a Ph). One way of making the code more DRY would be to automatically forward any public (meaning non private or protected) variables from the various object instances. To give more context:

- No sensitive data is handled by this API (Users, Order, Payments)
- The API is not public (Requires an Active Registered User)
- The data returned is all enriched data originating from the requestor's raw, non-structured data

To be more specific: What I mean by forwarding is to have the controller iterate through all public attributes of the used objects and automatically include them in the response object

So far the only cons I can think of is are:

- Developers accidentally exposing an attribute/variable by forgetting to make it private or protected
- Potentially exposing some traces of source code blueprints (But considering they would only be public vars/attributes and nothing else this one seems rather paranoid)

My guess is I'm missing more.

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping over it I realized that the biggest issue is coupling the contract with internal implementation which will inevitably become technical debt at some point later on. And the time saved is not enough to justify it.